# I want get username from session instead of parameter what is in url

Tags: flask, flask-login

```
@main.route('/about')
def user():
     return '<h1>Hello,%s</h1>' %user.email;

@main.route('/about/<username>')
def user(username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first();
    return '<h1>Hello,%s</h1>' %user.email;
```

can I get username from session or browser cookie?So I can set route concise. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can using only [flask's capabilities](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/views/#tutorial-views) (check section Login and Logout), if you store username in session. This can be done on login page, i.e.:

```
@main.route('/login')
def login():
    ...
    session["username"] = loggedin_username;

@main.route('/about')
def user():
    if 'username' in session:
        return '<h1>Hello,%s</h1>' % session["username"];
    return '<h1>Hello, Anonymous</h1>';
```

You can also refer to [flask-login docs](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#how-it-works) in order how to keep username in flask-login object, that is safer than keeping it in the session object.

Comment: My '/login' route is in auth blueprint.And '/about' is in main.So it this still usefull?

Comment: Yes. Your session is across your app not the blue print.